# Older date is not getting calculated correctly by using TZ=GMT+168

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to set up a purge process in unix. I have file retention period as 7 days. I tried to get the date as shown below. Can you please help me to understand why below command is not giving older date for GMT+168, GMT+192 and GMT+216 and so on.

```
$ TZ=GMT+24 date +"%m%d%Y"
10122019
$ TZ=GMT+48 date +"%m%d%Y"
10112019
$ TZ=GMT+72 date +"%m%d%Y"
10102019
$ TZ=GMT+96 date +"%m%d%Y"
10092019
$ TZ=GMT+120 date +"%m%d%Y"
10082019
$ TZ=GMT+144 date +"%m%d%Y"
10072019
$ TZ=GMT+168 date +"%m%d%Y"
10132019
$ TZ=GMT+192 date +"%m%d%Y"
10132019
$ TZ=GMT date +"%m%d%Y"
10132019
$ TZ=GMT+216 date +"%m%d%Y"
10132019
```

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu with GNU date. Which OS is this?

Comment: What `date` program version are you using? The `TZ=GMT+120` or anything bigger for TZ is an invalid value.

Comment: @KamilCuk : Could you please help me to understand how did we get result for TZ=GMT+144. It's working abnormally. Also, how can i get date program version ?

Comment: The standard doesn't specify what a utility should do when TZ is set to an invalid value. So the utility writer could have went with any way: discarding invalid values with an error or without, assuming some other value or simply not caring about what happens when the environment is not standard. Or any other way. The only way to answer "how did we get result" is to get the source code of your `date` utility and inspect it line by line. So, until you will specify what `date` utility version are you using, all are guesses. Most utilities have `--version` or `-v` or `-V` command line option....

Comment: I can guess it only takes the first 2 numbers from the GMT format and discards the rest. Can you confirm that ex. `TZ=GM+24123545` and `TZ=GMT+24` and `TZ=GMT+241` etc. give the same result? All these values are invalid except the first, the hours in GMT need to be lower then 24. See [posix environment variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Comment: As a side note, if you want to remove all files created 7 days ago or more, you should ask such question and show what you've tried, cause this looks like XY question. `date` TZ calculation is a different topic and it is not a way to add hours to current date.

Comment: Did you try `find path-type f  -mtime +7 -rm` ? When you did, why are lou looking for an other solution?

Comment: Yes, I used mtime option only to resolve the same. Thanks...!!!